# Можно ли на NUXT получать метатеги с API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Можно ли при открытии страницы получать метатеги с API (в функциях AsyncData или fetch) и подставлять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно. Я не знаток Nuxt'a, поэтому к моим словам не стоит относиться как к первородной истине, но я хочу попытаться направить поток ваших мыслей: Nuxt при установке мета-тегов использует `vue-meta` и вы можете перед экспортом конфига запросить необходимые данные у вашего API и использовать их в конфиге.

P.S. - Если вопрос был в том, имеется ли в Nuxt возможность получать мета-теги динамически из коробки - то нет, такой нет.

[Доки меты Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/meta-tags-seo/)